# stuck on hand tool and cannot get orbit mode

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a Unity beginner and sorry to ask this dumb question.
Usually, when I press alt, the hand tool changes to orbit (the eye mark) mode, but now press alt won't change to orbit mode and I'm stuck on move mode...

[image]

I did a research but could not find a clue to solve this issue.

Before it's stuck, I was adding layers to the terrain.
After I got stuck, I kill the Unity application and tried the same thing.

Could anyone please let me know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I get this.
Not sure why but I toggled 2D mode and that cause this problem.
Just needed to hit the '2D' button next to shaded solves this problem....